# Python - how to replace 'p' in a number(4p5) with '.' (4p5->4.5)?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a program that prints out some data with `'p'`s in place of decimal points, and also some other information. I was trying to replace the `'p'`s with `'.'`s.

Example output by the program:

```
out_info = 'value is approximately 34p55'
```

I would like to change it to:

```
out_info_updated = 'value is approximately 34.55'
```

I tried using `re.search` to extract out the number and replace the `p` with `.`, but plugging it back becomes a problem.I could not figure out that pattern to use for `re.sub` that would do the job.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import re
out_info = "value is approximately 34p55"
re.sub(r'(\d+)p(\d+)', r'\1.\2', out_info)
```

The output is:

> `'value is approximately 34.55'`

That says "Look for one or more digits, followed by a `p`, followed by one or more digits, then replace all that with the first set of digits, followed by a `.`, followed by the second set of digits."

Comment: `(\d)p(\d)` would be enough and is a lot faster (I just timed it with a string consisting of random floats, and the simpler regex is 8 times faster).